# Why performance.hasOwnProperty('getEntries') returns false while typeof performance.getEntries returns function?

Tags: javascript, performance, window, typeof, hasownproperty

Window property performance has a function call getEntries to retrieve all performance entries. which works on all modern browsers but doesn't work on a few older browsers like Safari 10. To add a check of working browsers....

If we try to verify using `performance.hasOwnProperty('getEntries')`, It always return false.
But it works if use  `typeof performance.getEntries === 'function'`.

Would like to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: what js doing is: if you call `performance.getEntries` and JS doesnt find it. it goes up the prototypal chain to look for it. with "going up" i mean this here `performance.__proto__` and searches. if its there in that case it is `performance.__proto__.hasOwnProperty("getEntries") // true`. in case JS doesnt find it keeps going up the chain `performance.__proto__.__proto__` and so on. the last item in the chain is the base object of javascript. if you try to go 1 more up you will receive `null` so `null` is the end of the chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

performance does not has own property “getEntries”， this property is owned by prototype of Performance, which is the constructor of performance object.

when you use performance.getEntries(), actually Performance.prototype.getEntries() is called.

Comment: Your answer along with @ifaruki 's comment and this article(https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework/blob/master/TCFv2/IAB%20Tech%20Lab%20-%20CMP%20API%20v2.md) helped me to understand the concept.

Thanks